# iteration through jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a jquery code which enables a user to select amount of money they wish to borrow and how long they would like to pay it back.

What I need to do is display the results in grid like table so that if a user wants to borrow $200 for 30days, they can pay 200/30 =$6.66 per day, so the grid would have day 1: 6.66, day 2: 6.66, day 3: 6.66 ...... up to day 30.

I have tried using iteration

created a variable called days

```
for( var i=i; i<days; i++) {
    //display days and amount
}
```

Any help?

Why display the amount everyday if it is the same amount?
Because there is a slider somewhere in the code and the user can vary the amount and dates to see what their repayments would be on daily basis, it is part of a larger code

Comment: If every day has the same repayment why would you bother repeating it for *every day*? What benefit does the user get from seeing the same value repeated 30 times?

Comment: so what is the issue ?? if jquery issue then put here code and be specific in your question

Comment: write the var in the loop, but why every day if it's the same

Comment: Because there is a slider somewhere and the user can vary the amount and dates to see what their repayments would be on daily basis

Comment: if you have a table could try any code like this: var i = 15; var days = 30; while(i<days) { $('tr').append('<td> | '+ i +' | </td>'); i++; }, for example.

Comment: Excellent @AlexBall, you gave me just the info I was looking for. Just one question please, with the current code, I get one table row and several columns, supposed I had 30 columns and I wanted to split it into six so that I have 6 columns and five rows, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to start with, just expand from here:

HTML:

```
Borrow Amount: <input type="text" id="borrow_amt" value="" />
<input type="button" id="update" value="Update Repayment" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<table border="1">
<tr><td colspan="30" align="center"> REPAYMENT SCHEME </td></tr>
<tr id="days"></tr>
<tr id="repayment"></tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.td_days { padding: 10px; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#update').click(function() {

        $('tr#days').html("");
        $('tr#repayment').html("");

        var days = 30;
        for (i=1; i <= days; i++) {
            $('tr#days').append('<td class="td_days">'+ i +'</td>');
        }

        for (i=1; i <= days; i++) {
            $('tr#repayment').append('<td class="td_days">'+ $('#borrow_amt').val()/30 +'</td>');
        }
    });

});
```

### ​

Part of the code c/0 @Alex Ball's suggestion, so give him a credit.

See code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/DHYHx/

Comment: Thanks @Dexter supposed I had 30 columns and I wanted to split it into six so that I have 6 columns and five rows, is that possible

Comment: @user1430825 That is possible, although you will consume more codes. I can't help you with that anymore cuz I need prepare and go somewhere right now. good luck.